# Is the sentence "Long weekend is coming..." correct?

Tags: articles

Can i write "Long weekend is coming..." or it is mandatory to use an article like "a" or "the"?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more appropriate to say:

> **A** long weekend is coming.

But if the sentence is used informally, then just the phrase "Long weekend is coming" should also be fine.